# Will the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2-n-1}{n!}$ converge when it runs from 1 to infinity?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2-n-1}{n!}$$

I usually divide by $n$ or $n^2$ but I'm unable to do so because of the factorial term.

Comment: Hint: $\frac {n^2-n-1}{n!}$ is very small, smaller than say $\frac{1}{n^2}$ for large $n$.

Comment: Hint: how does $n^2-n-1$ compare with $n^2-n$?

Answer (score 2):

The series evaluation:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^{2} - n - 1}{n!} &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{(n-2)!} - \frac{1}{n!}\right) \\
&= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n-2)!} - (e^{1} -1) \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} - (e^{1} - 1) = e^{1} - (e^{1} - 1) = 1.
\end{align}

Convergence by ratio test:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n+1)^2 - (n+1) - 1}{(n+1)!} \cdot \frac{n!}{n^2 - n -1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n+1} \cdot \frac{1 + \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n^{2}}}{1 - \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n^{2}}} = 0.$$
Since the limit is less than one the series converges.

Answer (score 1):

For $n\ge2$ render the summand as

$\frac{n^2-n}{n!}-\frac{1}{n!}$

Then, in the first term, $n!=(n)(n-1)(n-2)!=(n^2-n)(n-2)!$.  Not only does the series converge, it telescopes!  Can you thereby find its sum?

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^2-n-1}{n!}=-1+\sum_{n\geq 2}\left(\frac{1}{(n-2)!}-\frac{1}{n!}\right)\stackrel{\text{telescopic!}}{=}-1+\frac{1}{0!}+\frac{1}{1!}=\color{red}{\large 1}. $$